# Personal and Global messaging database design

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am trying to implement a database design system that will be sending messages to a person(thus 1 to 1) or many persons (1 to many).

```
    table --users
              |u_id | Name |
              | 01  | Aku  |
              | 02  | Sika |
              | 03  | Admin|

    table --messages 
              |m_id | sender_id | Body   | Time |
              | 100 |  01       | hello  | 16:04|
              | 200 |  02       | Hi     | 16:08|
              | 300 |  03       | hi Guys| 19:12|

    table --recipient
              |r_id| m_id | recipient_id| 
              | 50 | 100  |  02         |
              | 51 | 200  |  01         |
              | 52 | 300  |  01         |
              | 53 | 300  |  02         |

    table --message_status
              |m_id | recipient_id | status | deleted |
              |100  |   02         | read   |  no     |
              |200  |   01         | unread |  no     |
              |300  |   01         | read   |  yes    |
              |300  |   02         | unread |  no     |
```

From my schema above, a user can send a message to one person and he can also send a message to many persons.Once a user sends a message to a person, we will have all the recipients `userid` in the `recipient` table as well as in the `message_status` table . So assuming a user is sending one message to 1 million users at a time, it means, there will be a 1 million rows in both the `recipient` and `message_status` table.

Please can there be a way to handle this by reducing the many insertion of rows when a user sends a message to many users or that is the right thing to do.

**NOTE**

Please the system should allow every recipient to delete a recieved message if he/she so wishes, however their delete should not affect other recipients. So if user with `u_id = 02` deletes her recieved message, user with `u_id=01` should still view his message.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: It would seem that the relationship between persons and messages is really many-to-many.  If so, you should make that clearer in your question.

Comment: You should see my answer to this question on Stack Overflow, where I go into quite a bit of detail for essentially the same requirement: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541302/thread-messaging-system-database-schema-design/6542556#6542556

Answer (score 1):

You could combine `recipient` and `message_status`.  That would halve the number of inserts.

Comment: Yea thanks,but that still means that i would still be inserting one message Id for say 1 million recipients